# What are alternative ways for debugging spring boot apps using micro service architecture without accessing UI?

Tags: java, spring-boot, debugging, microservices, accessibility

I recently joined a company as a backend developer that is working on a spring boot project with microService architecture plus zeebe workflow engine and one or two NodeJs micro services.
This app has Gui, but since I'm blind and the gui is not accessible for screen readers, I can not use it properly.
Other developers open a web page and copy request and response headers from browser's developer tools and hit an Api with a rest client like postman.
I can do this with some screen reader tricks but it is hard for me and I am looking for alternative ways.
Imagine you have only backEnd part of an app as lots of micro services without UI. how do you debug or find part of the code that you think is buggy?

1. How do you find which micro service is responsible for requested bug without accessing UI?
2. how do you obtain requests headers and payloads without getting them from UI?

I know that is maybe an unusual request, but please share this question with everyone that you think may have a good answer because this is very important for me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Log copiously and debug by examining the logs.

Add lots of logging throughout you code. All logging frameworks support logging levels, both the level to write the log message with and the finest level that the server is configured to log with.

Often APIs support a header param to lower the log level for the call. Eg the server may be running with log level WARN, but if you hit its API with header `log.level=TRACE` you’ll see more log messages.

It is also good practice the use a call identifier in the header, which is passed on to downstream systems, and all systems add this to their logging so a single API call from the client can have all logs stitched together to get a complete picture of what happened.

There are also log aggregators, like splunk (very expensive) and LogStash (free) that support searching and collating logs.

Logging is a large topic, and I’ve only touched on a few points here. Read up and follow best practices. You’ll solve your particular challenge and improve your enterprise.

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian, but if I can not go through the ui, no endpoint will hit and no log will be generated for that request.

Comment: @hamidreza75 who said anything about a UI? You can use command line tools like curl or write system testing code that hits the endpoint (such tests  must surely exist already). And examining logs is just reading a text file or stdout (which can be redirected to file)

Comment: OK. @Bohemian imagine I want to write a test to hit an Api. I received a bug request that says, when finishing the registration process, we are getting 500 error. 1. How can I find out which endpoint called? 2. how can I create a payload with right info?

Comment: We have a micro service  that calls another micro services. So, just getting request url from testers does not solve my problem.

Comment: @hamidreza75 in a typical best practice service there should at least be a log message with the 500 details and a log message with the (sanitized) request details.